# Run a ROG G751JY without a battery

Tags: battery

I am having some serious problems with my G751JY, where the battery is always at 0% and won't charge - and on top of that I believe this makes the laptop shut down whenever it gets a little stressed (games, stresstests etc.). I think this is happening because when the laptop is stressed it needs to take some extra energy from the battery, but since my battery is dead the computer turns off. My hope is that if I take out the battery completely that it will stop to try to get energy from any other places than the PSU - which in turn will make my computer usable again.

So the question is; did anybody try to run their G751JY after completely disconnecting it? Or is there anything else you might think could help my situation?

Comment: Sorry, you need to replace the battery.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem running it with the battery removed. Just be sure foreign materials don't enter the open battery compartment and terminals. The fact that it shuts down while under load might be indicative of a different problem however.

Comment: Yeah I figure i need to replace the battery, but its hard to get in my country so I am just trying to make it work while I wait for the imported battery. What would you suggest is the problem @wysiwyg? I am 99% sure its not a heat problem because its shuts off normally when its not hot, the GPU and CPU can be at 50 C degrees and it happens. Earlier today it shut down when i tried to open chrome..

Comment: Hard to know exactly, it could be a number of things. You might be right that it's just the battery and removing it will fix it, or it could be an internal short somewhere else. Or it could be an entirely different component (hard drive, cpu, etc) that's failing.

Comment: Yeah, I am lost. I already disassembled it and everything looked ok. The thing is that my computer never turned itself off like this before - it happened only after the battery died and didnt want to charge. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my G751JY-DB73X. With the battery removed the laptop will not turn on so this method can't be used to get the laptop to run on mains power.

Thankfully the battery is available and only 80 dollars.